# Trying to enter values in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to extract certain part of the string and storing them in an array.
Here is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = ob.next();
    int l = ob.nextInt();
    int t = s.length();
    String arr[] = new String[10];
    String x;
    int i, j;
    int k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        x = s.substring(i, i + l);
        arr[k] = x;
        k++;
        System.out.println(arr[k]);
    }
}
```

The array values are appearing out to be null.

Comment: You set the element `arr[k]`. Then you increment `k`. Then you print out the element `arr[k]`. That is the element _after_ the one you just set.

Comment: Why not just call `s.toCharArray()`?

Comment: Please learn to use step-by-step debugging.  You would've seen it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue. Suppose that `k` is `0`

```
arr[k]=x; // arr[0] = x
k++;      // k = k+1 = 1
System.out.println(arr[k]);  // print arr[k] = print arr[1] -> null
```

Print before incrementing `k`:

```
arr[k]=x;
System.out.println(arr[k]);
k++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using k++ after printing so any way that value is not populated and printing null.Second you are doing s.substring(i, i + l) so in loop if you do till t then it will throw exception

```
Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = ob.next();
        int l = ob.nextInt();
        int t = s.length();
        String arr[] = new String[10];
        String x;
        int i, j;
        int k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < t-1; i++) {
            x = s.substring(i, i + l);
            arr[k] = x;
            System.out.println(arr[k]);
            k++;
        }
```

Comment: i liked the second one but it is not complete what if i enter `aaaa` and length = `4` it still throw `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range` please check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in your code :

**First :**

You have to increment your k after you print the value of the array

**Second :**

You will get `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range ...` error, because you loop from 0 to n and you are using `s.substring(i, i + l);` which can lead to this error, so to solve this problem you can use :

```
for (i = 0; i < s.length() - l + 1; i++) {
//--------------^________________^
```

---

Your code should look like :

```
Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the String :");
String s = ob.next();

System.out.print("Enter the length :");
int l = ob.nextInt();

String arr[] = new String[10];
String x;
int i, j;
int k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < s.length() - l + 1; i++) {
    x = s.substring(i, i + l);
    arr[k] = x;
    System.out.println(arr[k]);
    k++;
}
```

---

**Note** to help your users to use your program, add some message like i do before.

```
System.out.print("Enter the String :");
...
System.out.print("Enter the length :");
```